# Is std::streampos source-compatible with std::ios_base::streampos?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am managing a codebase that makes use of `std::ios_base::streampos` (specifically, the `tellg()` method of input streams) in a header file, that's included in several other files, and as expected, the compiler is making a lot of warnings about its deprecation, and how I should use `std::streampos` instead.

Is `std::streampos` just something I can replace the variable and function types with? Or does it remove methods or modify method functionality from `std::ios_base::streampos`?

The [C++ class documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base) for `ios_base` says:

> `streampos`(deprecated)   unspecified type that may be used like `pos_type`, not necessarily `std::streampos`

Does this mean `std::ios_base::streampos` is functionally equivalent to `std::ios_base::pos_type` (which itself is `std::fpos<std::mbstate_t>`) and by extension `std::streampos`?

Answer (score 0):

The direct replacement (`std::ios_base::streampos` was *removed* in C++17) is `std::basic_ios::pos_type`; there is no `std::ios_base::pos_type`, since `ios_base` is shared by all character types.  For `std::char_traits<char>`, that is indeed `std::streampos`.